# Is there an acceptable value for the absolute magnitude of horizontal branch stars?

Tags: absolute-magnitude

I'm writing a test for a gen-ed level astronomy class that I teach, and would just like a good reliable number to use as the basis for a distance calculation question.

And yes, I know that real astronomers use the RR Lyrae stars, but the text were using hasn't introduced variable star standard candles yet.

Looking at some H-R diagrams in textbook the answer seems to be vaguely around magnitude 0, and I'll use that value in the absence of something more definitive.